# Opentelemetry python not working when running via multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, open-telemetry

I am trying to run a python application which calls a function test using a multiprocessing pool.

The test function implements seperate tracer and create spans.

When this test function is called directly it is able to create tracer and span but when ran via multiprocessing pool, it is not working. Can anyone help on this

Tried running without pool and worked fine